# widget text isn't showing up in one of the column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doing a kivy tutorial and idk what's wrong with my code. My text "First Name" isn't showing up, but the others do like "Last name" and "Email"

I tried asking a friend and he said he doesn't see any problem.
This is the video I'm going off. His works, skip to 5:30 to see. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGWHQA3LhJ8

code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="First Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Last Name: "))
        self.last_name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.last_name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

It should show `First Name`:

[image]

Comment: At first the variable was first_name and still had same result. I’m so confuse on what’s the problem, still having same problem.

Comment: @AlexTaylor `name` is not a built-in function. For reference, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is the list of the built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install another version of sdl2.
The issue is known. [randomly transparent text](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6318)

Try install `kivy.deps.sdl2==0.1.18`