# How do I restart kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So my problem in my other post [widget text isn't showing up in one of the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248912/widget-text-isnt-showing-up-in-one-of-the-column) 
Apparently it works for my friend on his side.
But on my side it doesn't work.

Tried restarting computer, restarting visual studio code numerous times.

How do I fix this? What do I gotta restart, do I gotta kill anything in task manager?

Comment: I checked code from link and it works correctly on Linux. Problem can be only on Windows and you should go to Kivy's page and ask authors. They have [page for issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install another version of sdl2.
The issue is known. [randomly transparent text](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6318)

Try install `kivy.deps.sdl2==0.1.18`